# Prime number generator in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, primes

I am slowly learning C and C++, and decided after a few lessons to dive in myself without any help. I developed this prime number generator. It seems fast, but I'm wondering if I'm **following the best practices for C++**, or if I am missing anything important.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
bool checkPrime(int Number);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int currentNum;
    currentNum = 2;
    do {
        if (checkPrime(currentNum)) {
            printf("%d ", currentNum);
        }
        currentNum++;
    } while (1 == 1);
    return 0;
}

bool checkPrime(int Number){
    for (int a = 2; a < Number; a++){
        if (Number % a == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: to check for a prime, no need to loop all from 2 to n, just odd numbers from 2 to sqrt(n) is enough

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A few things in addition to what [@Jamal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal) and [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) already wrote:

- `g++` on Mac OS X won't compile this code, because of `#include "stdafx.h"` and the `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` signature. It's good to keep your code portable, unless you have a special reason not to. `g++` can compile if you drop the `stdafx.h` import and if change the `main` declaration.
- ... and since you're not using the arguments of `main`, you could just declare without any args: `int main() { ... }`.
- As you already used `true` in the `checkPrime` function, why not use it in the infinite `while` loop in `main`, instead of `1 == 1`.
- This may be a matter of taste, but I think `while (true) { ... }` is generally more readable and intuitive than `do { ... } while (true)`.
- ... actually, as @200_success pointed out, a `for (int currentNum = 2; ; currentNum++) { ... }` loop would be even better: this way `currentNum` is declared in the block where it is used, eliminating potential side effects, and the counter is a natural element in a `for` loop. Notice the empty terminating condition, making this an infinite loop.
- In `checkPrime` you named the variable `int Number`, but the common convention is to not capitalize variable names, use simply `int number` instead.
- As [@leetnightshade](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12987/leetnightshade) pointed out, place the opening curly either always on the same line as the function name ("Egyption brackets"), or always on the next line.

#### Suggested implementation

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int a = 2; a < number; a++) {
        if (number % a == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    for (int currentNum = 2; ; currentNum++) {
        if (isPrime(currentNum)) {
            std::cout << currentNum << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles with `g++` without warnings and runs fine in Mac OS X and GNU/Linux. I would hope it works as expected in Windows too.

Comment: To be consistent all functions should not have Egyptian brackets, or all should.  Right now `main` and `isPrime` are inconsistent in that regard.

Comment: @leetNightshade: What are `Egyptian` brackets. Not heard that term before. Though I agree with the general comment.

Comment: @LokiAstari Egyptian brackets are placing the opening curly on the same line as the function name eg: foo(){ as opposed to foo()\n{ (using \n to signify new line as I cant put one in a comment.)

Comment: @Vality hmm, weird name for standard K&R bracing. But indeed not proper for C++.

Comment: @jwenting I am not sure where the term came from, I think it is the term used for that style of brackets in Java where K&R style would have no meaning. However it is easy enough to guess what is meant in C also. Personally I always prefer the next line as else my eyes have trouble matching pairs of brackets but it is a valid style in some conventions.

Comment: @LokiAstari I believe it's from [New programming jargon you coined? on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2801919/445517) (deleted). [Image](http://www.muppin.com/quilts/egyptian.jpg)

Comment: And in the `isPrime` function, you can change the check for `a < number` in the `for`-loop to `a * a < number`.

Comment: @jwenting I had not heard of the K&R style.  Now that I know there is a proper name, I'll start using that. Thanks!

Comment: @jwenting Here's a visual for you, Egyptian brackets aren't the same thing as the K&R indenting, as K&R uses mixed brackets. http://pdgeeks.com/images/posts/egyptian-brackets.png

Answer (score 20):

- In C++, you should now use `std::cout` and `std::cin` instead of `printf()` and `scanf()` respectively.  These are found in [`<iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream), and you'll no longer need `<stdio.h>`.

  Example of `std::cout`:

  ```
  int number = 1;
  std::cout << "Number: " << number;
  ```

  Example of `std::cin`:

  ```
  int number;
  std::cin >> number;
  ```
- `currentNum` just needs to be initialized, not declared and then assigned:

  ```
  int currentNum = 2;
  ```
- The `do while` loop condition should just be `1`, not `1 == 1`.  This still equates to `true`.
- You can put `main()` below every function, eliminating the need for function prototypes since it will already know the existence of these functions.
- You don't need `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  This is a special case in that the compiler will automatically insert `return 0` as reaching this point always indicates a successful termination.

Comment: Beware: iostreams vs. stdio is controversial among C++ programmers. Definitely avoid scanf, though.

Answer (score 16):

One thing you might want to look at is more efficient code.  You're running a loop for each number you want to check.  Using a Sieve of Eratosthenes means you do all your looping once and the index of the vector returns true or false according to whether it's prime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<bool> MakePrimes(int upperlimit)
{
    int bound = (int) floor(sqrt(upperlimit));
    upperlimit++;
    std::vector<bool> primes(upperlimit, true);

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;
    //Since 2 is a special case if we do it separately we can optimize the rest since they will all be odd
    for(int i = 4; i < upperlimit; i += 2)
    {
        primes[i] = false;
    }
    //Since the only ones we need to look at are odd we can step by 2
    for (int i = 3; i  <= bound; i += 2)
    {
        if (primes[i]) 
        {
            //Since all the even multiples are already accounted for we start at the first one 
            //and skip to every other multiple
            for (int j = i*i; j < upperlimit; j += i * 2)
            {
                primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
int main()
{
    int limit = 1000;
    std::vector<bool>checkPrime = MakePrimes(limit);
    int currentNum = 1;
    while (currentNum++ < limit)
    {
        if (checkPrime[currentNum]) 
            std::cout << currentNum << "\n";
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This loop…

```
int currentNum;
currentNum = 2;
do {
    if (checkPrime(currentNum)) {
        printf("%d ", currentNum);
    }
    currentNum++;
} while (1 == 1);
```

… would be better written as a `for` loop:

```
for (int currentNum = 2; /* TODO: fix overflow */ ; currentNum++) {
    if (checkPrime(currentNum)) {
        printf("%d ", currentNum);
    }
}
```

For readability, `checkPrime()` should be renamed `isPrime()`.  Its parameter should be named `number` (lowercase).

You are using a brute-force trial division algorithm.  That works, but when you want a list of *many* prime numbers, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a much more efficient algorithm.